# Drawing heatmap with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap

I am trying to draw a heatmap with d3 using data from a csv: this is what I have so far

Given a csv file:

```
row,col,score
0,0,0.5
0,1,0.7
1,0,0.2
1,1,0.4
```

I have an svg and code as follows:

```
<svg id="heatmap-canvas" style="height:200px"></svg>

<script>
d3.csv("sgadata.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) { 
    d.score = +d.score;
    d.row = +d.row;
d.col = +d.col;
});
//height of each row in the heatmap
//width of each column in the heatmap
var h = gridSize;
var w = gridSize;
var rectPadding = 60;

$('#heatmap-canvas').empty();

var mySVG = d3.select("#heatmap-canvas")
.style('top',0)
.style('left',0);

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([-1, 0, 1])
.range([colorLow, colorMed, colorHigh]);

rowNest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.row; })
.key(function(d) { return d.col; });

dataByRows = rowNest.entries(data);
mySVG.forEach(function(){
var heatmapRow = mySVG.selectAll(".heatmap")
    .data(dataByRows, function(d) { return d.key; })
    .enter().append("g");

    //For each row, generate rects based on columns - this is where I get stuck
    heatmapRow.forEach(function(){
    var heatmapRects = heatmapRow
        .selectAll(".rect")
        .data(function(d) {return d.score;})
        .enter().append("svg:rect")
                    .attr('width',w)
        .attr('height',h)
        .attr('x', function(d) {return (d.row * w) + rectPadding;})
        .attr('y', function(d) {return (d.col * h) + rectPadding;})
        .style('fill',function(d) {
            if(d.score == NaN){return colorNA;}
            return colorScale(d.score);
                 })

})
</script>
```

My problem is with the nesting. My nesting is based on 2 keys, row first (used to generate the rows) then for each row, there are multiple nested keys for the columns and each of these contain my score. 
I am not sure how to proceed i.e. loop over columns and add rectangles with the colors

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you could used a `subselect` (see [d3.js building a grid of rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457170/d3-js-building-a-grid-of-rectangles)) to work with nested data in `d3` it's not really needed in this case.  I put together an example using your data at http://jsfiddle.net/QWLkR/2/. This is the key part:

```
var heatMap = svg.selectAll(".heatmap")
    .data(data, function(d) { return d.col + ':' + d.row; })
  .enter().append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return d.row * w; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.col * h; })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return w; })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return h; })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.score); });
```

Basically you can just use the `row` and `col` to calculate the correct position of the squares in your heatmap.

Comment: Sorry for the extension. I didnt know if I should post this as a new question, but is there a way to size the rectangles so that they fit in the div they are put in? if there is no predefined width for the div (i.e. varies depending on screen size?)

Comment: You can just grab the size of the `div` immediately prior to drawing the heatmap and then calculate the `height` and `width` based on the number of rows and columns.

Comment: I cant grab the size of the div if it hasen't been set, can I?

Comment: Something has to be set that you can use to calculate the correct size of the div.  Either the size of the div or the size of the window. There is no way to draw an SVG image without setting the height and width of the SVG container.

Comment: I am seeing spaces between rectangles when opened in firefox :( Its not that visible when the blocks are large but at a small height/width you can see them. Is there a way around this? http://jsfiddle.net/QWLkR/6/

Comment: I don't see any spaces with the latest Firefox, so seems to be a rendering issue with the version you are using. You can try added `shape-rendering: crispEdges;` to your CSS for the cells.

Comment: Here is what it looks like on chrome: http://i.imgur.com/wbyJs.png vs firefox: http://i.imgur.com/r9UH8.png
for me. I'll try the crisp edges

Comment: I'd open up a new question, not sure what FireFox is doing there.

Comment: Crisp edges worked! It messes up the stroke (on mouseover) a bit but I'll figure that out! Thank you so much