# D3 heatmap without explicitly storing row and column

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a 2d array of data that I'd like to visualize as a heatmap in D3.

From the examples I've seen, including:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12925448/1647819

http://bl.ocks.org/2605010

it looks like you have to encode the row and column as attributes of each data element.  Is there a way to take advantage of the structure of the data (i.e., the fact that it's a 2D array indexable with [i][j] notation) to avoid redundantly encoding the position information?

If not, is there a concise and/or efficient way to generate the data structure that encodes the position information?  By that I mean something other than a nested for loop:

```
myData = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
myDataWithPos = []

nRow = myData.length
nCol = myData[0].length

for (i = 0; i < nRow; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < nCol; j++){
        myDataWithPos.push({val: myData[i][j], row: i, col: j})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can use the indices of a 2d array to draw a heatmap.  I put together a quick example at http://jsfiddle.net/uArga/4/.

Assuming that your data looks like this:

```
var data = [[3,5],[9,2]];
```

First I set up some basic scales to calculate the `x` and `y` offsets based on the size of the data and the size of the chart. This makes it easy to resize the chart by changing the `height` and `width` without having to manually recalculate how big each of the cells should be.

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0,data[0].length]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, height])
    .domain([0,data.length]);
```

You can then add each row to the heat map

```
var row = svg.selectAll(".row")
             .data(data)
           .enter().append("svg:g")
             .attr("class", "row");
```

And then add each cell to the row using a subselect. There might be a cleaner way to do this but I basically just capture the row number alongside the data for each cell. I then use the scales to figure out the `x`, `y`, `height`, and `width` for each cell.

```
var col = row.selectAll(".cell")
    .data(function (d,i) {return d.map(function(a){return {value: a, row: i};})})
  .enter().append("svg:rect")
    .attr("class", "cell")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(d.row); })
    .attr("width", x(1))
    .attr("height", y(1))
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.value); });
```