# images ds3.js heatmap

Tags: r, d3.js

I am having trouble determining if you can create a heatmap  with DS3 or R that can map onto a list of icons. Specifically wanted to use little people icons like these http://goo.gl/Yt8CG and then show concentrations of activity onto them. I am fairly new to data visualization with DS3.js and R so I might not be doing the right google-fu. Thanks ahead of time if anyone can show me an example or let me know if you CAN do shading on icons not just dynamically generated blocks like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic approach is no different from drawing a normal heatmap (see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925266/drawing-heatmap-with-d3)). The only difference would be that instead of appending rectangles, you append a container for the graphic that you want to use.

Whether you would be able to adjust the shading depends on the graphic itself -- if it's a bitmap you're out of luck. If it's an SVG for example you can simply select the path inside that SVG and set the fill color just like you would for a rectangle in a normal heatmap.